# NetworkManager connection sharing doesn't seem to NAT packets

Tags: ubuntu, networking, arch-linux, nat

After setting up [network sharing the easy way](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3063/share-wireless-connection-with-wired-ethernet-port) on the Ubuntu machine, and getting an IP address via DHCP on the Arch Linux machine downstream, the Arch machine is able to `ssh` to the Ubuntu machine and resolve DNS, but not communicate with the Internet (`ping`, `pacman` time out). From the Arch Linux machine:

```
$ ip route show dev net0
default via 10.42.0.1 metric 202
10.42.0.0/24 proto kernel scope link src 10.42.0.15 metric 202
$ ip addr show dev net0
...
inet 10.42.0.15/24 brd 10.42.0.255 scope global net0
...
```

On the Ubuntu machine:

```
$ ip addr show dev eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether e8:11:32:66:e3:4d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.42.0.1/24 brd 10.42.0.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::ea11:32ff:fe66:e34d/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
$ ip addr show dev wlan0
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 88:53:2e:1b:4b:1c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.64/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global wlan0
    inet6 fe80::8a53:2eff:fe1b:4b1c/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Could it be that the automatic NAT setup on Ubuntu failed? I'm not sure how that works, so how would I detect that?

Comment: Can I answer Internet share using iptables ?

Comment: @RahulPatil If it explains how in a concise manner, sure. The goal is to solve routing in the simplest manner possible.

Comment: you mean "10.42.0.1" should act as gateway/router for other computer in network ?

Comment: once check with enable ip forwarding then let me know. http://www.ducea.com/2006/08/01/how-to-enable-ip-forwarding-in-linux/

Comment: IP forwarding was enabled.

Comment: Did you set up iptables to use NAT?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae No, since I'm looking for a NetworkManager solution (it obviously *should* work, since they have the functionality built in).

Answer (score 1):

Only one thing puzzles me, here: you say that DNS from the Arch machine is working.  If your DNS server is your Ubuntu box, great.  If your DNS server is external, then I'm confused.  I'm not intimately familiar with Arch — only installed it once — but you can usually check `/etc/resolv.conf` to see who your DNS servers are.  If they are internal, most likely your NAT or forwarding on the Ubuntu box aren't working.  If they are external — which means you are successfully resolving DNS queries against an external host — your problem is likely an iptables issue.

From a "what's likely to go wrong" perspective, it's far more likely to be forwarding/NAT.  So: verify forwarding is, indeed, enabled on the Ubuntu box:

```
fireapple# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/forwarding 
1
```

If it returns "0", likely your forwarding isn't enabled.  To temporarily fix it, simply

```
fireapple# echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/forwarding
```

To make it last through a reboot, edit /etc/sysctl.conf and add (or modify to look like) the following line:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Next, a quickie how-to-set-up-NAT script.  Plug the following into, say, `NAT.sh`, make sure you've `chmod +x`'d it, and put it in `/usr/local/bin/`.  Note that I've made assumptions about which interface is doing what, based on the fact that both hosts have 10.42.0.0/24 addresses:

```
#!/bin/sh
export INTERNET=wlan0  # Assuming eth0 is your Internet-facing address
export INTERNAL=eth0 # Likewise, assuming your WiFi is internal
iptables --flush      # Clean slate
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $INTERNAL -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i $INTERNAL -o $INTERNET -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i $INTERNET -o $INTERNAL -j ACCEPT
```

Once that's in-place, execute it (e.g., `sudo /usr/local/bin/NAT.sh`); if all goes well, you should be able to talk freely to the outside world.